# Upgrading JQuery is making all of my javascript not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate

I am trying to update my jquery library.  At the moment I am using jquery 1.3.2 (compressed) which in turn allows everything I have written for my javascript pages to work perfectly.  However, when I try to upgrade to jquery-1.10.2 (compressed) and as well as the jquery-migrate-1.2.1 (compressed) - It seems that all my javascript pages no longer work...at all.  If I update my jquery library, does that mean I have to reconfigure/rewrite everything in my javascript pages to accommodate the new updates?  Or is there something I'm missing or do not know about?

Is this the correct order to place these files in?  If so, why isn't it working with my javascript pages?  I also have them at the very bottom of my html page due to google pagespeed saying it's the best place to put them...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/JQuery/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/JQuery/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/NoS_Scripts.js"></script>
```

The above seems to make all my javascript (NoS_Scripts) invalid and not work...What I do have that works correctly and seamlessly is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/JQuery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/NoS_Scripts.js"></script>
```

And that does work perfectly - however, I'd just simply like to upgrade/update the jquery library to one of the latest versions out there which still is being used for IE6, 7, and 8.  I was told 1.10.2 and the migrate 1.2.1 would do the trick, but it's not...Any feedback of why this is occurring would be much appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to modify `NoS_Scripts.js`, there is no other way other than not upgrading. The migrate plugin only helps with 1.6.4+, 1.3.2 is too old.

Comment: So basically if I want to update/upgrade my jquery, I have to literally rewrite all my current javascript stuff to suit whatever version of jquery I decide to upgrade/update too?

Comment: you might not have to rewrite ALL of it, just a few specific things that changed between 1.3.2 and 1.6.4

Comment: If that's the case, do I even need the migrate-1.2.1 and only stick with the 1.10.2 ?

Comment: Well, if you don't include the migrate, you'll have to upgrade your code from 1.3.2 to 1.10.2 rather than from 1.3.2 to 1.6.4

Comment: It might help to see any of the NoS_Scripts.js content that is failing; some idea of what's failing; any console error messages, etc. 

jQuery has changed since then.. again, without seeing specifics, it's hard to say whether you'll need to "literally rewrite" all your code. Probably not *all*, of course.

Comment: @KevinB Unless I'm misreading it, 1.6.4 is the oldest "New" version of jQuery that can be used with jQuery-migrate, not the oldest "Old" version.

Comment: I know 1.3.2 is very old - in a way deprecated...That's why I'd like to update my jquery using one of the latest versions out there...but when I do - it messes almost all my javascript up...Is there no other alternate or hack around this?

Comment: *"The plugin can be included with versions of jQuery as old as 1.6.4 to identify potential upgrade issues via its JQMIGRATE console warnings. However, the plugin is only required for version 1.9.0 or higher to restore deprecated and removed functionality."* Therefore, if you upgraded your code to be compatible with 1.6.4, it would be compatible with 1.10.2 if the migrate plugin was included.

Comment: "Is there no other alternate or hack around this?" There's no one-size-fits-all fix for all possible scripts, no. And we have no idea what specific problems you're seeing.

Comment: Isn't 1.10.2 one of the latest versions out there as opposed to 1.6.4?  I know there are later versions out there than 1.6.4 so I'd like to upgrade to a later version instead of 1.6.4...Anywho, so what it boils down to is that if I do upgrade to 1.10.2 and include the migrate-1.2.1, I'd have to update my current javascript (not all)?

Comment: You don't have to worry about changing from .live to .on, or .bind to .on, or even .attr to .prop because all of those are covered by the migrate plugin. However, changes to the syntax of .animate and .ajax are things that you DO have to fix. There are also some changes to how selectors are handled (it's stricter now)

Comment: I think i'm confusing you, i'll try to clear it up. This shoudl be your planned upgrade process: Upgrade from 1.3.2 to 1.6.4. Once your code works correctly in 1.6.4, include the jQuery migrate plugin and 1.10.2 and watch the console. The console will tell you what changes you need to make to make it compatible in 1.10.2 without needing the migrate plugin.

Comment: Alright, that makes more sense.  Btw, I updated my original post, it will be quite long so please bare with me.  It's all the javascript I wrote which is in the NoS_Scripts.js file

Comment: @KevinB Are you sure you're reading that right? The way the documentation is worded, jquery-migrate works together with jQuery 1.6.4+ ("can be included with jQuery 1.6.4") to warn about deprecated code. It doesn't say that you had to originally code against 1.6.4 in order to use jquery-migrate.

Comment: I'm not saying that. You can use it with any version of jQuery greater than 1.6.4. I'm only mentioning 1.6.4 because it's the closest version to 1.3.2 that will work with the migrate plugin.

Comment: @user2732875 at first glance, I don't see anything in your code that should fail in 1.6.4, or even 1.10.2+migrate plugin. What error are you getting?

Comment: Here is a fiddle of just the javascript I have, I put the jquery at 1.10.1 - http://jsfiddle.net/tcXUW/  Also, I honestly do not know what errors are being thrown at me, no error logs are showing up...

Comment: @KevinB Ok, I think you're right - I read the documentation as if you could upgrade from an old version (like 1.3) to 1.6.4+ and use the plugin to help you upgrade there, but nothing on their docs or blog mentions anything older than 1.6.4, so I think I just interpreted their documentation incorrectly.

Comment: If you aren't actually seeing errors, that typically means your selectors aren't working. Start from the top and inspect the return value of each selector you use to ensure it's selecting the appropriate elements. `console.log($(suspectselector).length)`

Comment: Good lord, this will take me awhile...I appreciate your feedback on this and I do plan on updating/upgrading - Needless-to-say, Thank you, and I'm off to start crunchin' all this out ;) --> Quick question though, I use cPanel to access my files for my site, where and what exactly does `console.log($(suspectselector).length)` get placed and symbolize/mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to more than likely rewrite your NoS_Scripts.js file if you decide to update to one of the latest jquery libraries.  Especially if you are using a very outdated version.  Here is some information that should help guide you in the right direction.

For more information, view JQuery's main website: http://jquery.com/

API Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/

Versions: http://jquery.com/download/